# Prevent apt-get update from getting i386 packages?

Tags: apt

I'm on **64**-bit Lubuntu 14.04 LTS. I keep the system fully updated by running `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` twice daily.

However, I notice that `apt-get update` "gets" both i386 *and* amd64 packages for nearly everything. For example:

```
Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages [5,859 kB]
```

and

```
Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages [5,866 kB]
```

I've run `dpkg -l | grep ":i386"` but I just get back the prompt, indicating, I think, that I have no i386 packages installed.

My reason for asking is that if I could prevent the "getting" of i386 packages during `apt-get update`, I save my bandwidth and lessen the load, however marginally, on Canonical's servers.

Comment: @muru, will running `dpkg --remove-architecture i386` stop apt-get update from getting i386 packages? If so, I can delete my question.

Comment: It should. `apt` tried to get all supported architectures from repositories, unless you specifically state in `sources.list` that the repository should use a given architecture. Don't delete your question. Just mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @muru, Just one more clarification please... `dpkg --add-architecture i386` will reverse `dpkg -- remove -architecture i386`?

Comment: Yes, it should.